# PHP nusoap server - ksoap2 client (Soap Envelope) error at call

Tags: php, xml, wsdl, nusoap, android-ksoap2

EN: I'm work with PHP and Android. I'm using nusoap to make a WSDL server AND ksoap2 to client. I'm receive error of parser when try execute method call from androidHttpTransport

I use the WSDL in PHP the WSDL code and execute without error.

> ERROR:
>   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:455 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4054fe80)

variables

```
private final static String WEB_SERVICE_URI = "http://172.224.116.242/test.php";
private final static String WEB_SERVICE_NAMESPACE = "urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com";
private final static String WS_METHOD_GET_TOKEN = "SBPublish.getToken";
```

code in Android (ksoap2 - client)

```
            SoapObject parameters = new SoapObject(WEB_SERVICE_NAMESPACE,
            WS_METHOD_GET_TOKEN);

    parameters.addProperty("username", "test@aldeiati.com");
    parameters.addProperty("password", "123456");
    parameters.addProperty("deviceIMEI", "000000000000000");
    parameters.addProperty("deviceDDI", "us");
    parameters.addProperty("deviceNumber", "15555215554");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = this.getEnvelope(parameters);
    String host = this.getWebServiceURI();

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(host);
    androidHttpTransport
            .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;


    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(WS_METHOD_GET_TOKEN, envelope);
        SoapObject response =(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        return response.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (XmlPullParserException xe) {
        xe.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

This is my WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com"
>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
 <xsd:complexType name="Token">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="token" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="expireIn" type="xsd:long"/>
   <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:int"/>
   <xsd:element name="error" type="xsd:int"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="SBPublish.checkServerRequest">
  <part name="nome" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="SBPublish.checkServerResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:token" /></message>
<message name="SBPublish.syncServerRequest">
  <part name="token" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="data" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="SBPublish.syncServerResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="SBPublish.getTokenRequest">
  <part name="mail" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="deviceIMEI" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="deviceDDI" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="deviceNumber" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="SBPublish.getTokenResponse">
  <part name="return" type="tns:Token" /></message>
<portType name="smspublish.aldeiati.comPortType">
  <operation name="SBPublish.checkServer">
    <documentation>Testando o servidor</documentation>
    <input message="tns:SBPublish.checkServerRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:SBPublish.checkServerResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="SBPublish.syncServer">
    <documentation>Transmite ao servidor o registro as atividades realizadas e recupera novas atividades</documentation>
    <input message="tns:SBPublish.syncServerRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:SBPublish.syncServerResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="SBPublish.getToken">
    <documentation>Gera um token para comunicaÃ§Ã£o entre o dispositivo e o servidor</documentation>
    <input message="tns:SBPublish.getTokenRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:SBPublish.getTokenResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="smspublish.aldeiati.comBinding" type="tns:smspublish.aldeiati.comPortType">
  <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="SBPublish.checkServer">
    <soap:operation soapAction="SBPublish.checkServer" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="SBPublish.syncServer">
    <soap:operation soapAction="SBPublish.syncServer" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="SBPublish.getToken">
    <soap:operation soapAction="SBPublish.getToken" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
</binding>
<service name="smspublish.aldeiati.com">
  <port name="smspublish.aldeiati.comPort" binding="tns:smspublish.aldeiati.comBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://172.224.116.242/test.php"/>
  </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

This is what my android make

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<n0:SBPublish.getToken id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com">
<username i:type="d:string">test@aldeiati.com</username>
<password i:type="d:string">123456</password>
<deviceIMEI i:type="d:string">000000000000000</deviceIMEI>
<deviceDDI i:type="d:string">us</deviceDDI>
<deviceNumber i:type="d:string">15555215554</deviceNumber>
</n0:SBPublish.getToken>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

This is a response receive in soapUI using the xml make by android

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:SBPublish.getTokenResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:smspublish.aldeiati.com">
         <return xsi:type="tns:Token">
            <token xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</token>
            <expireIn xsi:type="xsd:long">180000</expireIn>
            <status xsi:type="xsd:int">authorized</status>
            <error xsi:type="xsd:int">200</error>
         </return>
      </ns1:SBPublish.getTokenResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I use this xml in soapUI to test web service, the XML created by Android is correct.

In android make a exception when call execute:

```
httpTransportSE.call(WS_METHOD_POLL_SERVER, envelope);
```

Comment: Well, you should post the XML so that one can take a look where that error relates to.

Comment: I Found the error, my URL is Wrong is past the WSDL url, but the ksoap2 need of url End Point. Thanks.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer to your question. You can then after some time accept it as the solution. That will mark your question as solved and might help somebody else seeing a similar error message.